# Copy to clipboard classic asp

Tags: html, sql, vbscript, asp-classic, copy

I want to copy a row from a table that is printed from recordset to clipboard so the user does not have to select text and copy. Is this possible to do in classic asp?

Comment: **Check this answers:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: ASP runs on the server - there is no clipboard for ASP.  Clipboards are only available on the client through something like javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read all About it! ;)
[Javascript Copy to Clipboard](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/javascript-copy-to-clipboard.html)

this is supposed to be a crossbrowser JS solution to copy to clipboard (but I haven't tested it) [Copy To ClipBoard - Cross Browser](http://www.dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/copyToClipboard/)